# ruby method wont return false

Tags: ruby, return

i have method, which returns either an array (if it contains any elements) or false if it is     nil:

```
def check_for_four
    @four = []
    check_values.each do |key, value|  ###check_values return hash with key and values as numbers
        @four << key if value == 4
    end

    if @four == nil
        return false
    else
        return @four
    end     
end
```

but later on, if i call a method

```
if some_object.check_for_four
    puts "true"
else
    puts "false"
end
```

it always return true, even if @four array is empty. Why is that?

Comment: nil and empty are not the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking for whether the array is nil (i.e. is the singleton instance of `NilClass`) which is very different to checking whether the array is empty.

To check where the array is empty you can either call `empty?` or if you actually want to check whether it is not empty, you can also use `any?`.

You can of course also do things like check that the length/size is zero, but it feels more rubyish to me to ask for the specific thing you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

An empty array is 'truthy' in Ruby. For example:

```
puts "foo" if []
```

will output "foo" but

```
puts "foo" if nil
```

won't output anything.